# Is there any software that can reliably change my IP address without having to unplug router?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, dns, ip

Alright, so, there is a certain website that keeps… I'm not sure exactly what the right term is… attacking, hacking, my computer, I guess? With a DNS spoofing or DNS cache poisoning attack, and diverting me to a very annoying and unwanted pornographic website. Anyway, long story short, I try running things like Malwarebytes and such to get rid of it; it doesn't get rid of it (possibly because it's not actually *on* my  computer, per se?). I don't know, whatever, it's getting extremely frustrating and I don't have the wherewithal to deal with trying to get rid of it anymore, I just want to get around it!

The easiest workaround to be able to get back on the site without having to deal with the stupid DNS spoofing spam/nuisance is simply to change my IP address, though that is still easier said than done. I was able to do it by unplugging my wireless router, letting it sit for about an hour, then plugging it back in. Obviously, I don't feel like having to deal with this every time I get infected with this nonsense. Is there any simple, user-friendly software that would allow me to just edit my IP address without any hassle?

I have tried IP Change Easy, but it seems to be too confusing for me, despite the deceptive name. It has all these things with profiles, different types of network connections, (I don't know which is the one I need) MAC, all this stuff; I can't get it to work, when I try, I either still show up as having the same public IP address, or I just can no longer access the internet at all (saying things like “This webpage is not available” regardless of what site I type in). So, what should I do here?

Comment: If it happens after you changed your IP, then it's something on your machine/router, unless it's actively targeting your particular PC, which seems unlikely and impossible without some kind of software clientside to notify this "attacker" about the IP change. Have you checked that your DNS settings are correct? They could have been changed and never reset by a previous adware problem.

Comment: @Jonah No, after I changed my IP, I was able to access everything just fine. I'm talking about in the future, for the next time this occurs. Based on what I've heard from other users of the particular site, this is something that can keep happening, frequently and continuously. :/

Comment: Does it only happen on this particular website?

Comment: @Jonah Yes, it's the only place I've ever encountered it.

Comment: You could use [tor](https://www.torproject.org/) to redirect your internet traffic through an external device. Then, if it happens, you can create a new tor identity and the website will see it as if your IP has truly changed, because the external relay that you're viewing through now has a different IP.

Comment: @Jonah Ok thank you, I'll try that! Now to start trying to get tor to work for me, yet again…

Comment: If it is being triggered externally, they don't have access to your internal IP address, just the IP address of your router as assigned by your Internet service provider.  The way to change that is to ask your service provider to assign you a new IP address (that won't change any of your internal IP addresses).  If the problem only happens at one web site, it probably means that it was the web site that was targetted, not you.  You might want to alert the web master at that site.

Comment: @fixer1234 The problem **does** only happen at that one website, and it **is** so, that the website was targeted, not me. I **do** believe that the webmaster (or at the very least, an admin of the site) is aware of the problem, this individual has made several youtube videos giving advice about how to ameliorate the problem, (which included the aforementioned advice about DNS flushing from an admin command prompt and such) none of which seemed to give any benefit for me. Perhaps I still should email the site itself at its main contact form, and alert them again as to the situation.

Comment: @fixer1234 As far as the IP address of my router and all that… you're talking about having to ask my service provider to be assigning me this and that… I have neither the time nor the interest to be messing about with things like that, I just want to get… around… this problem, in the simplest, easiest, quickest way possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only one website, it could be some sort of problem at that specific website, an XSS attack for example. A friend of mine's WordPress was hacked once and they placed header redirections on the WordPress installation. If it's truly a DNS cache poisoning attack, you could use Google's DNS servers as pointed out by @user322035.

You can also try flushing out the DNS:

From a Command Prompt with administrator privileges:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: Hmm… okay. I already tried the ipconfig /flushdns thing, to no avail (yes, I was running it as an administrator). Yes, it is definitely a problem at that specific website. It **is** a DNS cache poisoning attack, at least according to someone who claimed to be an admin of the site, and he seemed believable. I really don't know much—I'm no expert—I just repeat and follow what seemingly more knowledgeable people say to do. Is there any kind of a good tutorial anywhere you could direct me to, that would instruct me how to use google DNS servers as pointed out by @user322035?

Comment: Windows+R (opens the run dialog)->type in "ncpa.cpl" (without quotes) -> Right Click on your Network Adapter (could be Local Arena Network or Wireless Network Connection) -> Select "Properties" on the Menu -> Select Internet Protocol Version 4 -> Click on Properties -> Check the "Use the following DNS Server Address" option -> Put both google DNS servers: 8.8.8.8 Primary. 8.8.4.4 Secondary.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! That was so detailed and technical, I could have never figured it out myself, and I couldn't find any other tutorial to explain it. Thank you so much for helping me solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Is your assigned DNS server actually being changed, or are you being redirected to these sites by browser malware stuff?  Try hardcoding the DNS server.  You can use anything you want. 8.8.8.8 is google.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like it could be a good solution, I'm not 100% sure, but I think it is just browser malware stuff?… sooooo… how would I go about doing that, hardcoding thing?

Comment: Find the network connections-> properties on your adapter[ethernet?]->ipv4->properties-spec a DNS. THis will override any DNS you get from DHCP, from your router, etc.  You can even do this in your router.

Comment: Ok… again, I'll say, it certainly _sounds_ like a good solution… again, I wouldn't know for sure, as I'm no expert when it comes to any of this advanced networky-type stuff… I'm just an end user… I sign into Windows, I open programs, I browse websites… I don't know anything about coding or configuring or anything like that, unless someone gives me detailed, specific instructions on how to perform the task. In other words, please explain like I'm five. What and where are the network connections? Is there any kind of a good tutorial anywhere you could direct me to?

Comment: I found this: [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-xp/help/networking/manage-network-connections) which seems like it _might_ be trying to tell me something about how to do this, but it's all for Windows XP… I have Windows 7, and I can't really seem to find the menus and what-have-you that would be analogous to the ones this is directing me towards. (๏̯͡๏﴿